# Why does CStr not work on Intersect Range?

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, intersection

I have some code that works on worksheet change event. It selects the intersect of columns C:E and their Row with the following code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const fRow As Long = 2
    Const cCols As String = "C:E"
    Const dCol As String = "A"
    
    Dim lngth As Range
    Dim LogEntryID As String, LogSearchRange As Range, R As Range
    
    
    Dim crg As Range
    Set crg = Columns(cCols).Resize(Rows.Count - fRow + 1).Offset(fRow - 1)
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(crg, Target)
    
    
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Intersect(irg.EntireRow, crg)
    Dim AreaString As String

     AreaString = CStr(srg)
```

If for example Debug.Print for Srg is something like srg: C16:E16 why does it come up with type mismatch if I attempt to do  AreaString = CStr(srg)? How would I get the string output of my intersect value?

Comment: `srg.address` Sounds like what you are looking for.

Comment: @Warcupine I was hoping to get the intersect as an exact string without the single-$ type srg.address produces i.e $C$21:$E$21.

Comment: `Address(False, False)` gives the relative address (no $)

Comment: Or loop through the intersect range and concatenate the individual cell addresses if that's actually what you are trying to achieve (and what I have understood you may be trying to do from the comments).

Comment: @TimWilliams Today I learned .Address has parameters. Definitely the better method over replace.

Comment: @Warcupine Another great one is `Address(External:=True)`. That has been very helpful to me in many projects. Saves me from manually concatenating the sheet name and/or workbook name when inserting ranges into formulas.